# WAR file deployed to TomEE Plus not sending emails: loader constraint violation error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, windows-server-2012, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I deployed an EJB application (provided as a `.war` file) to TomEE Plus 7.1.0.

It runs alright, but it was noticed that emails were not being sent.

I investigated the log file at `logs/tomee-stderr.[date].log` and found this:

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance
>   of java/net/URLClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a
>   different type with name "javax/mail/Session"

followed by a very, *very* long <sub>(>500k lines)</sub> stack trace.

I found a related question *([java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/mail/Session"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34542266))* and it is said the solution consists in marking the dependency to `javamail` as a "provided" dependency, but my understanding is that this is supposed to be done in the Maven project file, to which I don't have access.

I can edit the contents of the ROOT directory at will (and I tried deleting two files, namely, `mail.jar` and `mail-1.4.4.jar`, from the `WEB-INF/lib` directory, but to no avail); I believe I can also edit the .war file with 7-zip; and finally I can modify any configuration in the server. But I *cannot* edit the application's source code and/or recompile it.

(As potentially relevant information, I do have read access to the source code, and it does not appear to use Maven - the existence of a `.project` file suggests it is an Eclipse project.)

A file named `geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.9.0-alpha-2.jar` is part of TomEE and is located in the `lib` folder.

Given my constraints (no maven, no compilation - existing WAR file must work), how can this error be solved?

[Edit 1]

- I removed both `mail.jar` and `mail-1.4.4.jar` from the WAR file (with 7-zip) and re-deployed, resetted the log file but the error remains the same.
- I tried deleting `geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.9.0-alpha-2.jar` from TomEE's `lib` folder, but TomEE fails to start.

Comment: It seems that there is still a jar file that contains the javax.mail.Session class? Please extract all the WEB-INF/lib to an folder and search for the content of all the jar files if it contains the string "javax/mail/Session"

Comment: @CChai There was, indeed! I removed it and the problem is solved. Post an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is still a jar file that contains the javax.mail.Session class? Please extract all the WEB-INF/lib to an folder and search for the content of all the jar files if it contains the string "javax/mail/Session"

Comment: Just for the record, the offending jar file was `geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar`. For some reason it did not show up on my file search and that's how it went unnoticed.